# Create Custom circular progressbar with two layer

Tags: android, android-layout, layer-list

I want to create circular progress bar with two color

please Check image for Circular Progress Bar

[image]

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom drawable xml file and set this drawbale to your progressbar

Check below answer

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="1080">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="12"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <size
                android:width="76dip"
                android:height="76dip"/>
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:type="linear"
                android:useLevel="false"
                />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="1080">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="22"
            android:useLevel="false">

            <size
                android:width="76dip"
                android:height="76dip"/>
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:endColor="@android:color/white"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="false"
                />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

set this drawable to your progress bar

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loadingbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar" />
```

Hope this will help you

Put your second color instead of @color/colorPrimary